# PLSQL block to increase salary of departments

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to Increase the Salary of employees working in deptno 10 by 15%, Deptno 20 by 15% and others by 5% and display the corresponding the employees working in that Dept. I am able to increase the salary of departmnet 10 and 20 but I am not able to increase the salary of other departments by 5%. I have tried with for loop too.This is a practice question.

My question is this:(**Display the  all records  from the Dept table. Increase the Salary of employees working in deptno 10 by 15%, Deptno 20 by 15% and others by 5% Also display the corresponding the employees working in that Dept. Use a parameter Cursor and Cursor with Update clause.**)

MY code:

```
declare 
cursor sal_increase(v_dno number) is select empno,sal,ename,deptno from emp where deptno=v_dno ;
emp_record sal_increase%rowtype;
begin
OPEN sal_increase(10);
LOOP
FETCH sal_increase INTO emp_record;
EXIT WHEN sal_increase%NOTFOUND;
update emp set sal=sal+sal*0.15 where empno=emp_record.empno;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_record.ename||' '||emp_record.deptno);
END LOOP;
CLOSE sal_increase;
OPEN sal_increase(20);
LOOP
FETCH sal_increase INTO emp_record;
EXIT WHEN sal_increase%NOTFOUND;
update emp set sal=sal+sal*0.15 where empno=emp_record.empno;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(emp_record.ename||' '||emp_record.deptno);
END LOOP;
CLOSE sal_increase;
end;
```

Comment: Does this have to be done in PL/SQL? Can I do it in pure SQL?

Comment: yes it is specified to do this with pl/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the solution from **@sticky bit** for future.

Going back to your requirement , I believe you stick to do it with one anonymous block and  with parameterized cursor.(correct me if I am wrong)

if yes, I would change the following and it should do the work for you.

Change your cursor to below, For others you pass null as parameter and in the where clause we can handle the same. (when value pass as 10 or 20 it will do a comparison and when null it will update for all other than 10 and 20)

```
CURSOR sal_increase(v_dno NUMBER) IS
      SELECT empno
            ,sal
            ,ename
            ,deptno
      FROM   emp
      WHERE  (   v_dno IS NOT NULL AND deptno = v_dno 
              OR v_dno IS NULL AND deptno NOT IN (10,20)
              );
```

Then call again the cusrosr as you did for 10 and 20 once more like below,

```
   OPEN sal_increase(v_dno => NULL);
   LOOP
      FETCH sal_increase
         INTO emp_record;
      EXIT WHEN sal_increase%NOTFOUND;
      UPDATE emp SET sal = sal * 0.05 WHERE empno = emp_record.empno;
      dbms_output.put_line(emp_record.ename || ' ' || emp_record.deptno);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE sal_increase;
```

Comment: can you please see my question once i have updated it and this solution given by you works for me.

Comment: @mayank: when I see your updated question, the requirements also says "cursor with update clause". I am not sure if this update clause refers to your update statement in side the begin end or something like  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php.... because we can have actually cursor with update clause to handle locking when two concurrent users are updating the same records. See the link I provided for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any procedural code at all to do this. That would just unnecessarily and severely slow it down, especially the use of cursors.

Instead just use a simple `UPDATE` with a `CASE` expression returning the new salary depending on the department.

```
UPDATE emp
       SET sal = CASE
                   WHEN deptno IN (10, 20) THEN
                     sal * 0.15
                   ELSE
                     sal * 0.05
                 END;
```

For the output just use a `SELECT`.

```
SELECT ename || ' ' || deptno
       FROM emp;
```

Comment: I have to this question with PL/SQL its a assignment.

Comment: If you have to do it in PL/SQL, just wrap the simple update statement in BEGIN .. END.  Voila! You now have PL/SQL.